# Get Best Price button/element is not visible in firefox mobile (react js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1. "Get Best Price" Click to action disappears when user scrolls down the popup view more screen (*only in mobile firefox*).

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0lgq.png)

Comment: Hey! More information is needed if you want help with your problem. Code, screenshots, etc ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.